# Reliability of genetic tests

Tags: research-methods, dna

I have been considering getting a genetic test to get an idea of where my genes suggest my family has been. How reliable are these types of tests particularly as my ancestry seems to be spatially scattered?

Has anyone ever tried them before? If so, what are your experiences?

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking in terms of genetics, including inherited traits, good, neutral or harmful. But if this too close, then i can delete

Comment: No need to delete - even if it gets closed as too close to the other question then this one will just link through to that.